# What is best forum script available to integrate with wordpress?

Tags: multisite, bbpress, forum

Ok i have a wordpress site network. I would like to setup a support forum for my site. But i don't want users to signup in different pages. I mean i want my users to use the same wordpress login credentials in forum too. Is there any forum plugin available there. Thanks
PS: Is it possible using bbpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [Mingle Forum](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mingle-forum/) plugin, which is nice, simple and did the job for me on a couple of sites.

also [bbPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress/) looks promesing but its still in a beta stage like @Rarst pointed out.

and last you have [SimplePress](http://simple-press.com/) which is by far the most feature rich forum plugin I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! bbPress is the best way to go. There are two options for you.
Either the standalone version or the new WordPress plugin named bbPress. Give them a spin, you will find the latter one easy to start up a forum but former has a good number of plugins, whereas the new plugin doesn't have much plugins as of now.

Comment: Note that plugin version is considered beta so far, might not be good idea to use it on large live network.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been testing out Vanilla forums and it works well, should check it out.